# recursive paths for libsass

Tags: recursion, gulp-sass, libsass

I am using `gulp-sass` to compile sass in `node.js`. I am using the `libsass` config to set the `includePaths` option.

The following code **works**:

```
includePaths: './project/components/controls/selectAgencies/'
```

...but I would like to do something with recursion and get the same result, something like one of the following possibilities. As it stands right now, with these settings I get error: "file to import not found or unreadable".

```
includePaths: './project/components/controls/'
// or
includePaths: './project/components/controls/**/'
```

In compass, this is as simple as setting `add_import_path "project/components"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually in my sass file. If my include path is

`./project/components/controls/`

and the sass file lives at

`./project/components/controls/selectAgencies/_selectAgencies.scss` then my .scss file should reflect the rest of the path, like so:

```
@import 'selectAgencies/selectAgencies'
```